# how to execute c program in windows command prompt when run from eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded and configured eclipse cdt along with MinGW and able to compile c programs.

My question, how to start executing the program in command prompt when Run option clicked from eclipse. Currently it always executes the program in eclipse console.

Reason to have command prompt for executing c programs is to accept user inputs.
I would also like to know is there a way to accept user inputs when c program running in eclipse console.

Thanks in advance,
-Manju

Answer (score 0):

I guess i am quite late but still you can try this out. You can execute c programs through Eclipse cdt by writing a batch file and calling them through a click of button or any other event handler. Just make sure you are in the correct directory before attempting to compile and execute the file.

You can find various resources online to create a batch file which can help you execute programs through the console.

On compiling the file, (if you haven't specified an output file), a.exe file will be created. To execute this file with command line inputs just type the following in cmd (as long as you are in the same directory)

> a.exe "command line inputs"

where "command line inputs" are the inputs you want to provide to your program.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

i know 8 years is very late,but maybe somone else like me see this,so my answer is :
you should use:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

after every printf statment to be able to input data in eclipse ide console tab ,
as i understood :""The root cause of the I/O problem is that we're using Windows pipes to communicate with the underlying process. The pipes are buffered"
you can refer to this links for more informations;

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Eclipse_console_does_not_show_output_on_Windows

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732